# how can i change the output of a fragment base in another fragment in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I made this code for an app it suppose to give a list of body part like arm and legs and one you click on one in the first fragment a list of exercise should appear in the second fragment this list is suppose to change if the user press another option and is there were I have the problem it displays the first option automatic but it not change after the user press another option please how can I change the content in the second fragment.

**Main class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements WorkoutListFragment.WorkoutListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WorkoutDetailFragment frag = (WorkoutDetailFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detail_frag);



    frag.setWorkoutId(1);
}

public void itemClicked(long id){
    int itemSelected = (int)id;
    String message = String.format("ID selected %d", itemSelected);
    Log.v("DEBUG", message);
}
}
```

**Second class**

```
public class Workout {
private String name;
private String description;

public Workout(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public static final Workout[] workouts= {
        new Workout("Chest Workout", "3 Bench Press\n10Flys\nWide Dips"),
        new Workout("Legs", "5 Squats\n3x12 Leg Curl\n3x10 Leg Press"),
        new Workout("Back", "10 Pullups\n 3x8 Dumbell Rows"),
        new Workout("Arms", "10 Biceps Curls\n10 Dips\n3x10 Preacher Curls")
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

**Third class**

```
public class WorkoutDetailFragment extends Fragment {
private final String TAG = "DEBUG";
private long workoutId;

public WorkoutDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view !=null){
        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextTitle);
        Workout workout = Workout.workouts[(int)workoutId];

        title.setText(workout.getName());
        Log.v(TAG, workout.getName());

        TextView description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextDescription);
        description.setText(workout.getDescription());
        Log.v(TAG, workout.getDescription());
    }

}

public void setWorkoutId(long id){
    this.workoutId = id;
}

}
```

**Fourth class**

```
public class WorkoutListFragment extends ListFragment {

static interface WorkoutListener {
    void itemClicked(long id);
}

private WorkoutListener listener;
public WorkoutListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.listener = (WorkoutListener)activity;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    if (listener != null){
        listener.itemClicked(id);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create a string array with workout names
    String[] names = new String [Workout.workouts.length];
    for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++){
        names[i] = Workout.workouts[i].getName();
    }

    // Create an array adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            names);

    // bind the adapter to the control
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // this call gives you the default layout view for the
    // ListFragment
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside an onClickListener or whatever listens for clicks you should write this in your activity:

```
FragmentManager fragementManager = getFragmentManager();
fragementManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout, new NextFragment()).commit();
```

In this example R.id.layout should be the id of your layout in where your fragment is placed. NextFragment should be the class of the fragment you want to display.
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I have a itemClicked in the first class

Comment: You need to replace it with whatever fragment you want

Comment: thank men it really help me a lot is finish. thanks again

Comment: Sure no problem. Just remember to select it as the correct answer.